# Android app: Gson crashed when reading List

Tags: java, android, json, gson

im working on an android app, that should parse basic timetables from public transportation. The basic part work very well, but i had an problem with an JSON List.

The JSON respone looks like this

```
{"Departures": [{
  "Id": "68496628",
  "LineName": "15",
  "Direction": "Munic",
  "Platform": {
    "Name": "4",
    "Type": "Platform"
  },
  "Mot": "Tram",
  "RealTime": "\/Date(1501101000000+0200)\/",
  "ScheduledTime": "\/Date(1501101000000+0200)\/",
  "State": "InTime",
  "RouteChanges": [
    "510322",
    "510447",
    "510448"
  ],
  "Diva": {
    "Number": "11015",
    "Network": "ooe"
  }]}
```

My Problem is to parse the Liste RouteChanges. Sometimes in the Response is the list empty, sometime is the an list like this. 
My code to get the list in Android looks like this:

```
 public static class Cast {

    private String name="0";

    public String getName() {
        Log.d("Model","String from first List-Entry is: "+name);
        return name;
    }


}
```

But in every case when i get an line with an RouteChanges-list my app crashed with the following Log-Mon-Message:

```
07-26 22:09:00.628 9578-17541/com.hisham.jsonparsingdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                       Process: com.hisham.jsonparsingdemo, PID: 9578
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                        Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 237 path $.RouteChanges[0]
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
                                                                           at com.hisham.jsonparsingdemo.MainActivity$JSONTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:149)
                                                                           at com.hisham.jsonparsingdemo.MainActivity$JSONTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:85)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 237 path $.RouteChanges[0]
                                                                           at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:387)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:189)
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40) 
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81) 
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60) 
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103) 
                                                                           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196) 
                                                                           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810) 
                                                                           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775) 
                                                                           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724) 
                                                                           at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696) 
                                                                           at com.hisham.jsonparsingdemo.MainActivity$JSONTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:149) 
                                                                           at com.hisham.jsonparsingdemo.MainActivity$JSONTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:85) 
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The line 149 in my MainActivity is the Gson-Line:

```
  Model movieModel = gson.fromJson(finalObject.toString(), MovieModel.class); // a single line json parsing using Gson
```

finalobject was created trough:

```
for(int i=0; i<parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

}

And the parentArray through an JSON Array, that splits the strings on the keyword "Departures"

Can you help me to read with gson through that list?

Thank you

Edit: The entire MovieModelClass:

```
public class MovieModel {

@SerializedName("RouteChanges")
private String LineName;
private String Direction;
private String State;
private String ScheduledTime;
private String RealTime;
private String HstOrt;
private String HstName;
private String HstId;

public static class Cast {

    private String name="0";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


}

public String getLineName(){return LineName;}
public String getDirection(){return Direction;}
public String getState(){return State;}
public String getScheduledTime(){return ScheduledTime;}
public String getRealTime(){return RealTime;}
public String getHstOrt(){return HstOrt;}
public String getHstName(){return HstName;}
public String getHstId(){return HstId;}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a curly brace "{" at the beginning:

```
    {
"Departures": [{
      "Id": "68496628",
      "LineName": "15",
      "Direction": "Munic",
      "Platform": {
        "Name": "4",
        "Type": "Platform"
      },
      "Mot": "Tram",
      "RealTime": "\/Date(1501101000000+0200)\/",
      "ScheduledTime": "\/Date(1501101000000+0200)\/",
      "State": "InTime",
      "RouteChanges": [
        "510322",
        "510447",
        "510448"
      ],
      "Diva": {
        "Number": "11015",
        "Network": "ooe"
      }]
}
```

This message is what gave me the idea of your error:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1

Change this line:

```
String LineName
```

for this:

```
List<String> LineName
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I only forgotten the curly brackets in my Question and updated it.

Comment: @Hans1357 Can you add the entire MovieModel.class ? to see how it corresponds to the json structure.

Comment: I added the class.

Comment: Why LineName ? I want to read the list from RouteChanges ? But i tested it and it comes to the same error message :/

Comment: you are using @SerializedName("RouteChanges") above that field. So you are mapping that field to RouteChanges.

Comment: It may be a dummy question but did you update the getter when you change string for List<String> ?

Comment: yeah i also update the getter to: `public List<String> getLineName() {
        return LineName;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"Departures":[
  {
     "Id":"68496628",
     "LineName":"15",
     "Direction":"Munic",
     "Platform":{
        "Name":"4",
        "Type":"Platform"
     },
     "Mot":"Tram",
     "RealTime":"\/Date(1501101000000+0200)\/",
     "ScheduledTime":"\/Date(1501101000000+0200)\/",
     "State":"InTime",
     "RouteChanges":[
        "510322",
        "510447",
        "510448"
     ],
     "Diva":{
        "Number":"11015",
        "Network":"ooe"
     }
  }
]}
```

Still a closing brace **}** was missing. You can always test your JSON in Postman or online [JSONformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)